# Copying <td> values to next <td> with numerical increment

Tags: html-table, copy, cell

I have a table with cells generated from `ajax()`. The final `HTML` table looks like this as an example:

```
<table id="sendMailTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 75px; text-align: center;">Table ID</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 100px;">Dated</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 140px;">RL/Tkt No</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody name="tblBody" id="tblBody">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 75px; text-align: center;">1</td>
      <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">04/12/2017</td>
      <td tabindex="1" autofocus="true" style="contenteditable=" true "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 75px; text-align: center; ">2</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle; ">04/12/2017</td>
            <td tabindex="1 " autofocus="true " autofocus="true "style="contenteditable="true"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 75px; text-align: center;">3</td>
      <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">04/12/2017</td>
      <td tabindex="1" autofocus="true" style="contenteditable=" true "></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 75px; text-align: center; ">4</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle; ">04/12/2017</td>
            <td tabindex="1 " autofocus="true " style="contenteditable="true"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 75px; text-align: center;">5</td>
      <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">04/12/2017</td>
      <td tabindex="1" autofocus="true" style="contenteditable=" true "></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Cells of the last column may Contain Only Numeric Values or Alpha-Numeric Values. Is there a way to fill the ALL Subsequent Cells of the last column with the incremented Numerical value from the immediate preceding Cell along with any Text Value? Like EK123, EK124 or 110, 111, 112. Etc. However the Value shall change only from the Present Focused Cell or `<td>` only.

The JS code is as follows:

```
$('.rlNum').bind("keyup", function(e) {
                       //on letter number
                        var IncrementedValue = '';
                       if (e.which <= 90 && e.which >= 48)
                       {
                        IncrementedValue  = IncrementedValue + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                        for (i = rowClicked +1; i <= totalRows; i++) { 
                            if (e.which <= 57 && e.which >= 48){
                                IncrementedValue = (Number($(this).text().replace( /^\D+/g, '')) + 1).toString();
                             }else if(e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90){
                                IncrementedValue = $(this).text();
                             }
                            var ele = $(this).parent().next().find('.rlNum');
                            window.alert( $(this).text());
                            ele.html(IncrementedValue);
                        }
                       }
                });
```

[The unsolved jsfiddle is at this link](https://jsfiddle.net/fpk6fvh8/2/)

Comment: Don't Try. I am getting Close. I will share the Code.

Comment: The code that i have developed till now is now placed in the main Question above. But there are two bugs. Firstly, Only immediate next <td> is getting updated and secondly the update is only Numeric Increment and the Alphabets are vanishing

Comment: If I can get Help with the `js` code that I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup got it after all this long efforts. The js code is as follows:

```
    $(document).on("click", "#sendMailTable tbody tr", function() {
        currentRow = ($(this).index()+1);
    });

    $('.rlNum').bind("keyup", function(e) {
                    var currentCellInput = $(this).text();
                    $(this).find('tr').click();
                    totalRows = $('table >tbody >tr').length;
                    for (m = currentRow + 1, j=1; m <= totalRows; m++,j++) {    
                        document.getElementById('sendMailTable').rows[m].cells[6].innerHTML = processStr(currentCellInput,j);   
                    }   
                });

    function processStr(str, x) {
    var result = str.match(/[^-_ \d]+|\d+/g);
    for (i = 0; i <= result.length-1; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(result[i])){
            result[i]= ((Number(result[i])) + x).toString();
        }  
    }
    result.toString();
    return (result.join(""));
}
```